# R: Cross reference vector with list, HELP: append new vector based on positive hits

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, append, cross-reference

I have a vector A and a list B of vectors v1, v2 and v3. I aim to combine the vectors in list B that contain one or more of the entries of A into a new vector (new_v).

```
A <- c("cat", "dog", "bird")
A

B <- list(v1 = c("mike", "fred", "paul"), v2 = c("mouse", "cat", "frog"), v3 = c("bird", "cow", "snake"))
B

new_list <- c()

for(i in names(B)){       
  
  v <- A %in% B[[i]]            ## test for elements of A in vectors of B
  print(v)
  
  if (TRUE %in% v){             ## if TRUE (A is in vector of B), 
                                ## add vector of B to new_v 
    
    append(new_v, unlist(B[i])) ## doesn't do what I want
    
  }
}
dput(new_v)
```

The result I was hoping for:

```
>dput(new_v)
c("mouse", "cat", "frog", "bird", "cow", "snake")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one-liner with `Map`.

```
unlist(Map(function(x, y) {if(any(x %in% y)) y}, list(A), B))
#[1] "mouse" "cat"   "frog"  "bird"  "cow"   "snake"
```

Explanation:

`Map` applies the anonymous function to every element of its list arguments. Since `list(A)` has length 1, it is recycled to the length of the list `B`.
As for the function, if any element of `x`, (the vector `A`) is in `y` (each of the vectors of `B`) then `y` is returned, else `NULL` is returned.

## Edit

If `B` has a `dim` attribute set, then it can be an object of class `"matrix"` or of class `"data.frame"` (or inheriting from one of those classes).

**1.** If it is a matrix, coerce to vector and there is no need for `Map`.

```
if(any(A %in% as.vector(B))) B
#     [,1]    [,2]              
#[1,] "mouse" "mice eat rats"   
#[2,] "cat"   "cats eat mice"   
#[3,] "frog"  "frogs frog frogs"
```

**2.** If it is a data.frame, `unlist` where it's `as.vector` above.

```
B2 <- as.data.frame(B)
if(any(A %in% unlist(B2))) B2
#     V1               V2
#1 mouse    mice eat rats
#2   cat    cats eat mice
#3  frog frogs frog frogs
```

Comment: Hi Rui, I tried to expand this code so it works with B as table but I'm not getting anywhere. I.e. `B <- structure(c("mouse", "cat", "frog", "mice eat rats", "cats eat mice", "frogs frog frogs"), .Dim = c(3L, 2L))`. I'd want to get the whole table back if one or more entries from A are found in B. I tried this, but seem like my logic is off: `(Map(function(x, y) {if(any(x %in% y[[1]])) y}, list(A), B))`

Comment: @Matt To have a dim attribute set changes things. Try passing `as.data.frame(B)` in my code above. Do you expect *both* columns to be returned? (Does `cat` in `A` match `cats` in `B[, 2]`?)

Comment: Awesome, that's better. Ideally both columns should be returned, although not searched. So only `B[, 1]` is searched, but if any `A` is in `B[, 1]`, the output should be `B[,1:2]`

Comment: WOW, awesome. Thanks so much for the in-depth edit! Helps a lot to get a grasp on the data types in R :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(list(A), B, ~ if(any(.x %in% .y)) .y) %>%
    flatten_chr
#[1] "mouse" "cat"   "frog"  "bird"  "cow"   "snake"
```

Comment: Thanks! What woul be the benefit of using Map2?

Comment: @Matt If you are interested in tidyverse approaches, it would gel well